# Pagination with total records count without duplicates and also with limit in aggregation query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is the query, I tried to aggregate and my requirement is to get total records count and also pagination that has limit of 15. I got the results but it seems to be there are duplicates. Please point out what am I missing.

```
db.collections.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "application_id": "some_app_id"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "localField": "_id",
            "from": "collection1",
            "foreignField": "some_id",
            "as": "merged"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {"path": "$merged"}
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
            "posts": {
                    "$push":"$$ROOT"
                }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$posts"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$posts._id",
            "data":{"$addToSet":"$posts"},
            "count": {"$first" : "$count"},
            "posts": {
                    "$push":"$$ROOT"
                }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id": 1,
            "count": 1,              
            "data": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

"count" : 89 // Here the count is actually 33 but i'm getting 89 somehow

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

"count" : 33 with no duplicates

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to do with your aggregate query, unless we know what it is supposed to do, we wont be able to debug if your aggregate query is working properly or not, or if not where is the issue. Also please show us your schema, it is helpful to check the correctness of the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I'm trying to merge two different collections by aggregating and I need the total records count initially before the skip and limit options because, finally i'm getting 15 records only! So, the count is 15 but actually the total records count is 33. Here in this query the count 89, which is the total of array of elements.

Comment: can you share the two schemas which you are merging?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti thank you, I have achieved this through **facet method** that's really awesome.